# Reading an input from a textbox and storing it in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `<textarea>` that allows text to be inputted in the form of a string. Then the users clicks on a button which displays what they have inputted back to them in a text area within a table.

I need to use an array to store what has been inputted by the user, and then display it back out into another `<textarea>` element within a table from the array, where the user input is stored from the input box.

Any pointers on how to fill up an array and stacks, from a user input would be great.

Comment: `var value = document.getElementById("id").value; var array = []; array.push(value);` and `array.pop(); or array[i]`

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your array like this

```
var yourArray = new Array();
```

or

```
var yourArray = [];
```

To add items to array:

```
yourArray.push(yourString);
```

To get you can use indexing like (almost any other language)

```
yourArray[i]
```

You can even set as an object array like this:

```
yourArray.push({ text : 'blablabla'})
```

So, in your case, filling up the array could be something like this:

```js
var inputText = document.getElementById('id_of_input').value;
yourArray.push(inputText);

// show it

for(var i=0; i<yourArray.length; i++) {
    alert(yourArray[i]);
}
```